# WPF MVVM Datagrid having Combobox update other column on selectedItem Change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am trying to get this done since a week now. I am developing a windows based application using MVVM framework which has a Datagrid which is bound to an observablecollection. First column is a Combobox which is bound to an item in a class. what I want to happen is, at the first load, grid should populate with values pulled from database with Combobox setup to appropriate value (THIS is working perfectly fine) but later whenever user changes combobox value, corresponding other columns to get updated (THIS Part is NOT WORKING) .... Please help!!!

Here is my XMAL, InstrumentType and Industry should get populated based on the value selected in Instrument Name combobox

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding obFundPartipants}"
                                    SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sr.No" Width="40"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Instrument Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--<ComboBox
                            ItemsSource=
                            "{Binding DataContext.lstInstrumentMasterAll, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}" DisplayMemberPath="InstrumentName"  
                                                             SelectedValuePath="InstrumentName"
                                                             SelectedValue="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.InstrumentName}" 
                                                             SelectedItem="{Binding InstrumentDetails, Mode=TwoWay}"   />-->
                        <ComboBox
                            ItemsSource=
                            "{Binding DataContext.obInstrumentMaster, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}" DisplayMemberPath="InstrumentName"  
                                                             SelectedValuePath="InstrumentName"
                                                             SelectedValue="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.InstrumentName}" 
                                                             SelectedItem="{Binding imSelectedInstrument, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Instrument Name" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.InstrumentName}" />-->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Instrument Type" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.InstrumentType}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Industry" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.IndustryName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pur Date" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=TransactionDate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=BalanceQty}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Buy Price" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=AveragePrice}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Invested Amount" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=AverageAmount}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cur Price" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Path=InstrumentDetails.CurPrice}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Current Value" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentAmount}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

View Model
    private InstrumentMaster _imSelectedInstrument; public InstrumentMaster imSelectedInstrument { get { return _imSelectedInstrument; } set { _imSelectedInstrument = value; base.NotifyPropertyChanged("imSelectedInstrument"); UpdateInstrumentDetails(); } }

    private ObservableCollection<Transaction> _obFundPartipants; public ObservableCollection<Transaction> obFundPartipants { get { return _obFundPartipants; } set { _obFundPartipants = value; base.NotifyPropertyChanged("obFundPartipants"); UpdateInstrumentDetails(); } }

public class Transaction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime   _TransactionDate;  public DateTime  TransactionDate  { get { return _TransactionDate; }  set { _TransactionDate = value;} }
    private String   _TransactionType;  public String  TransactionType  { get { return _TransactionType; }  set { _TransactionType = value;} }
    private int   _FundID;  public int  FundID  { get { return _FundID; }  set { _FundID = value;} }
    private int _PortfolioID; public int PortfolioID { get { return _PortfolioID; } set { _PortfolioID = value; } }
    private int   _InstrumentID;  public int  InstrumentID  { get { return _InstrumentID; }  set { _InstrumentID = value;} }
    private String   _InstrumentKey;  public String  InstrumentKey  { get { return _InstrumentKey; }  set { _InstrumentKey = value;} }
    private InstrumentMaster _InstrumentDetails; public InstrumentMaster InstrumentDetails { get { return _InstrumentDetails; } set { _InstrumentDetails = value; } }
    private String _InstrumentType; public String InstrumentType { get { return _InstrumentType; } set { _InstrumentType = value; } }
    private double   _TransactionQty;  public double  TransactionQty  { get { return _TransactionQty; }  set { _TransactionQty = value;} }
    private double   _TransactionPrice;  public double  TransactionPrice  { get { return _TransactionPrice; }  set { _TransactionPrice = value;} }
    private double _TransactionAmount; public double TransactionAmount { get { return _TransactionPrice * _TransactionQty; } set { _TransactionAmount = _TransactionPrice * _TransactionQty; } }

    private String   _TransactionNotes;  public String  TransactionNotes  { get { return _TransactionNotes; }  set { _TransactionNotes = value;} }
    private String _FundName; public String FundName { get { return _FundName; } set { _FundName = value; } }
    private String _InstrumentName; public String InstrumentName { get { return _InstrumentName; } set { _InstrumentName = value; } }
    private Boolean _TransactionFlag; public Boolean TransactionFlag { get { return _TransactionFlag; } set { _TransactionFlag = value; } }
    private DateTime _FundTransactionDate; public DateTime FundTransactionDate { get { return _FundTransactionDate; } set { _FundTransactionDate = value; } }
    private double _BalanceQty; public double BalanceQty { get { return _BalanceQty; } set { _BalanceQty = value; } }
    private double _AveragePrice; public double AveragePrice { get { return _AveragePrice; } set { _AveragePrice = value; } }
    private double _AverageAmount; public double AverageAmount { get { return _AveragePrice * _BalanceQty; } }

    private double _CurrentAmount; public double CurrentAmount { get { return _CurrentAmount; } set { _CurrentAmount = value; } }


    public void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class InstrumentMaster
{
    private Boolean _SelectedInstrument; public Boolean SelectedInstrument { get { return _SelectedInstrument; } set { _SelectedInstrument = value; } }
    private Boolean _Checked; public Boolean Checked { get { return _Checked; } set { _Checked = value; } }
    private int _InstrumentID; public int InstrumentID { get { return _InstrumentID; } set { _InstrumentID = value; } }
    private String _InstrumentKey; public String InstrumentKey { get { return _InstrumentKey; } set { _InstrumentKey = value; } }
    private String _InstrumentName; public String InstrumentName { get { return _InstrumentName; } set { _InstrumentName = value; } }
    private String _InstrumentType; public String InstrumentType { get { return _InstrumentType; } set { _InstrumentType = value; } }
    private String _ISINCD; public String ISINCD { get { return _ISINCD; } set { _ISINCD = value; } }
    private int _IndustryID; public int IndustryID { get { return _IndustryID; } set { _IndustryID = value; } }
    private String _IndustryName; public String IndustryName { get { return _IndustryName; } set { _IndustryName = value; } }
    private int _Active; public int Active { get { return _Active; } set { _Active = value; } }

    private int _PortfolioID; public int PortfolioID { get { return _PortfolioID; } set { _PortfolioID = value; } }
    private double _BalanceQuantity; public double BalanceQuantity { get { return _BalanceQuantity; } set { _BalanceQuantity = value; } }
    private int _PersonalFundID; public int PersonalFundID { get { return _PersonalFundID; } set { _PersonalFundID = value; } }

    private double _CurPrice; public double CurPrice { get { return _CurPrice; } set { _CurPrice = value; } }
    private String _CurPriceType; public String CurPriceType { get { return _CurPriceType; } set { _CurPriceType = value; } }
    private DateTime _CurPriceDate; public DateTime CurPriceDate { get { return _CurPriceDate; } set { _CurPriceDate = value; } }

}
```

Comment: You should call `OnPropertyChanged` for each property, which should affect changes in the UI, ie in `MainWindow`. Try to call it for `InstrumentType` property.

Comment: U also want to use a model inside your viewmodel and not duplicate all properties for whatever reason.

Comment: @Jim, I know I have a redundant code here which I need to cleanup. I do have another class (InstrumentMaster) referred within Transaction calss , its just that I was first trying to get it working and later do cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each setter of your properties must call `OnPropertyChanged("<property Name>")`

Comment: The values in the underlying class are getting updated , its just that they are not getting reflected on UI. I do have UpdateTrigger on Combobox but its not working

Comment: The UpdateTrigger in XAML is not your problem. In your code each setter of your properties must call OnPropertyChange so that the UI knows about changes.